# Delegate can be assigned to either anonymous method or lambda but not to a method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

In the following code snippet,

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Work()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }

    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Action a =  Work;
        Action b = async () => await Task.Delay(1000);
        Action c =  async delegate () { await Task.Delay(1000);  };
    }
}
```

delegates of type `Action` cannot be assigned to a method `Work` of type `Task` but weirdly can be assigned to an anonymous method or a lambda of type `Task`.

In my understanding

- `Work`
- `async () => await Task.Delay(1000)`
- `async delegate () { await Task.Delay(1000);  }`

have the same signature that are not compatible to `Action`. What causes this inconsistency?

## Edit:

The following lambda and anonymous method

- `async () => await Task.Delay(1000)`
- `async delegate () { await Task.Delay(1000);  }`

can represent both `Action` or `Func<Task>` depending on the left hand side of assignment. More precisely,

Converted to `Action` implicitly,

- `Action a = async () => await Task.Delay(1000)`
- `Action b = async delegate () { await Task.Delay(1000);  }`

Converted to `Func<Task>` implicitly,

- `Func<Task> a = async () => await Task.Delay(1000)`
- `Func<Task> b = async delegate () { await Task.Delay(1000);  }`

Is it @JSteward's comment below about?

Comment: `Work` is not an `Action`. When you assign the lambda or delegate you're creating `async void` methods, while `Work` returns a `Task`. You could assign that method to a `Func` instead.

Comment: "When you assign the lambda or delegate you're creating async void methods" <--- Oh really? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `Action` is a delegate of return type `void`:

```
public delegate void Action()
```

and your method has the return type `Task`.

Secondly, the return type of the anonymous method that is created by the lambda expression is determined by the type of the delegate (`Action`). Since the delegate is `void`, you are creating a `void` anonymous method. The return value of the `Task.Delay` call is discarded.

Further, your anonymous function from the `delegate()` expression is not of type `Task`, as you assume. It is of type `void`, since it does not have a `return` statement. It would not even compile if you added one, since you are trying to assign it to a delegate of type `void`:

```
Action c =  async delegate () { return await Task.Delay(1000);  };
```

gives the error message

> Anonymous function converted to a void returning delegate cannot return a value.

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity better now?

Answer (score 2):

Work is a function with the return type of Task, thats why you can't "put" it into an Action.

The only reason for your exemples working, is that the lambda function

```
() => Task.Delay(1000);
```

creates an Action that calls Task.Delay(1000).

```
void Function()
{
    Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

And when you create an async lambda

```
async () => await Task.Delay(1000);
```

creates an Action that awaits Task.Delay(1000).

```
async void Function()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
}
```

same applies to the anonymous function.

P.S.

When you await an async function, the Task output is changed to its "type" (in this case void). Thats why if you await Task.Delay(1000), you get void for the return type.